# How to iterate through classes of file in python?

Tags: python, django

I have a file called models with few classes and I need to iterate throw them in order to get each class to preform the same task on it.

**my problem**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models
# this is very repetetive
admin.site.register(models.Myclass)
admin.site.register(models.MySecondclass)
admin.site.register(models.MyThirdclass)
#.
#. 
#...
```

**my goal**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models


for class in models:
   admin.site.register(class)
```

- **If you can't understand django**

```
# models.py
import example

class Component():
    return example.Component

class Post():
    return "Post"

class Comment():
    return "Comment"
```

```
# the goal file
from . import models
# i need to get my models as list [Component,Post,Comment]
```

Comment: FWIW, I’ve done this in the past, but any serious Django admin will customize each model slightly to make it really usable, so you’ll end up with manual definitions in the end anyway…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) with passing [`inspect.isclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass) as its second argument for `predicate` will give classes. To further filter to prevent other classes imported from somewhere else, ensure `__module__` is `"models"`:

```py
import inspect

classes = [obj
           for _, obj in inspect.getmembers(models, predicate=inspect.isclass)
           if obj.__module__ == "models"]
```

gives `classes` as

```
[models.Component, models.Post, models.Comment]
```

after which you can do your `for`:

```py
for class_ in classes:
   admin.site.register(class_)
```

(using `class_` to not override `class` of Python).

Comment: @Mustafa_Aydin in my models file I have `import something` and i got returned in `classes` variable as well. So, how to filter them out.

clases= `[<class 'models.Component,'>, <class 'models.Postr'>, <class 'models.Comment'>, <class 'api.models.Comment'>, <class 'api.models.Component'>, <class 'api.models.ExtendUser'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'>, <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin'>, <class 'api.models.Post'>, <class 'django.core.validators.RegexValidator'>, <class 'api.models.Style'>, <class 'something'>]`

Comment: @All I edited the answer with an `if` for the module name only for the specific module, hope it helps. (Also pulled the `class` check inside the `getmembers` as a second argument).